# Path.approximate() not supported on android studio 0.8.14 beta

Tags: android, android-studio, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Rendering Problems

*Path.approximate() not supported.*

*Failed to parse file*

*~\sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\drawable\progress_medium_material.xml* error after add `ProgressBar` to `Layout`

How to resolve?

Comment: I've found that it is caused by the presence of <ProgressBar> tag in my fragment layout.

Comment: I want add `ProgressBar` to my SplashScreenActivity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested on a real device and it works. Just ignore the error.

Answer (score 10):

You can also switch rendering theme to `Theme.Black` and pick `API 20` version to render layouts in Android Studio.
[image: Android Studio toolbar]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but problem in Lollipop (API 21). Other APIs works perfect.

Comment: You can change the rendering theme, but there is still a problem on devices running Lollipop that the ProgressBar can't be seen.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a bug in the appcompat-v7:21.+

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77865

I've changed compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion in my app's build.gradle file from 21 to 20 and everything works now.