# Getting an error saying "Path.approximate() not supported" when I try to add a ProgressBar to the layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to add a ProgressBar to the layout, but I get this error in the xml's graphical layout:

```
Path.approximate() not supported
Failed to parse file
sdk\platforms\android-21\data\res\drawable\progress_indeterminate_horizontal_material.xml
```

I'm using Eclipse and I've tried updating the ADT plugin and the Build Tools, but it didn't help.

The error goes away when I select a lower API, but is there a proper way to fix this without changing the API?

Comment: your problem seems same like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26741111/path-approximate-not-supported-on-android-studio-0-8-14-beta

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the latest sdk which you have downloaded. The way to do it is :

Go to the tab `Window->Preferences->Android` and then select the sdk folder where you have installed your android sdk.

[image]

Comment: The sdk location is already set correctly, but I still get the error.